# Pythonでデータ型を確認したい。 typeとpprintの違いは？

Tags: python, python3

**Pythonの基本的なデータ型を確認したいのですが、**

---

**Q1.どうやって確認するのでしょうか？**
・type()?
・pprint()?
・両者の違いは？

---

**Q2.下記コードで結果に何も表示されないのは何故ですか？**
・type()はオブジェクト型のみが対象?

```
from fractions import Fraction
f = Fraction(5, 7)
type(f)
```

---

**Q3.Pythonでプリミティブデータ型という言い方をしますか？**

---

**Q4.分数について**
・「Fraction」で一つのデータ型ですか？
・意味合いで言えば、「int」や「float」と同等ですか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1.どうやって確認するのでしょうか？
・type()?
・pprint()?
・両者の違いは？
type()を使います。
pprint()は、複雑なデータを整えて表示する機能を持ちます。

```
import pprint

print([[i for i in range(10)]]*2)
pprint.pprint([[i for i in range(11)]]*3)
#print
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
#pprint
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Q2.下記コードで結果に何も表示されないのは何故ですか？
・type()はオブジェクト型のみが対象?

```
from fractions import Fraction
f = Fraction(5, 7)
type(f)
```

別の回答者様が書かれていますが、

```
print(type(f))
```

として初めて表示されます。
`type()`だけだと、`f`の型を取得はできても、出力表示するという
命令までは持っていないからです。
`type()`は、オブジェクト型のみが対象です。
オブジェクト型というのは、名前を付けることのできるものです。

```
b = "オブジェクト"
　　print(type(b))
<class 'str'>
def sai():
    return 1

print(type(sai()))
<class 'int'>
print(type(sai))
<class 'function'>
import re
print(type(re))
<class 'module'>
#cという名前のついたreモジュール
c = re 
print(type(c))
<class 'module'>
```

Pythonでは、変数名をつけられるものはすべてオブジェクトと
言っていいと思います。

Q3.Pythonでプリミティブデータ型という言い方をしますか？

「Pythonの基本的なデータ型を確認したいのですが」
という質問なので、Pythonの基本的なデータ型を、
プリミティブデータ型という言い方をしますか？という
質問だと判断します。
　Pythonの基本的なデータ型は、ビルトインタイプ、
ビルトイン型、組み込み型と呼ばれ、そのようには
呼ばれないです。

Q4.分数について
・「Fraction」で一つのデータ型ですか？
　そうです。
・意味合いで言えば、「int」や「float」と同等ですか？
　そうです。
　ただ、`int`は、**組み込み型**なので、`import`しなくても、
　即座に使えます。
　`Fraction`は、

```
from fractions import Fraction
```

とあるように、フラクションモジュールの中にある
　`Fraction`型です。モジュールの中に入っているか
　どうかの違いだけです。こういう、`Python`に最初から
　あるという点では**組み込み型**だけど、インポートが
　別に必要な場合を、**標準ライブラリ**と言います。
   これに、`pygame`や、`PyQt5`など、外部から別に持ってきた
　モジュールで、インストール後にインポートできるような
　ものを、**サードパーティーモジュール**と言います。
　ゆえに、**組み込み型**は、「特別な宣言や命令なしに
　利用できる型」と言えます。
　導入にちょっと段階がいるだけで、データ型であることは
　変わりません。

Comment: プリミティブデータ型のくだりで言い換え例に組み込み型が出てくるのはおかしくないでしょうか。プリミティブデータ型をどのような意味に捉えていますか

Comment: 私は初めて聞く言葉でしたので、wikiで調べました。　　　　　　　　プリミティブ型（プリミティブがた 英語: primitive data type、プリミティブデータ型）は、データ型の1分類である。例として、代表的なプリミティブ型を一部列挙:
文字型 (character, char);
整数型 (integer, int, short, long, byte)（各種の精度のものがある）;
浮動小数点数 (float, double, real, double precision);
固定小数点数 (fixed) （各種の固定精度やスケール指定可能なものがある）。
真値と偽値をもつブーリアン型(ブール代数)。
参照型 (ポインタまたはハンドルとも言われる)、オブジェクトを参照する小さな値で、そのオブジェクト自身よりも大きな容量のオブジェクトも扱える。こんなかにpythonで使われるものが含まれ、それが組み込み型なのでそうだと判断しました。完全に一致するものとして言い換えるのは確かに違うのではないかと思いつつ。似たような位置づけにあるという風に考えました。

Comment: すいません。連投ですが、質問の全体の趣旨が、Pythonのデータ型に関する話ということで、Q3の質問のプリミティブ型についても、Pythonのデータ型をそう呼ぶことはあるか？という質問だと解釈しました。「プリミティブ型自体が、Pythonのデータ型と言い換えられるか？」というような質問だと、完全には一致しないと考えています。うまくはいえませんが。

Comment: Pythonの標準ライブラリの『[4. 組み込み型](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/stdtypes.html)』を読むとわかりますが、「主要な組み込み型は、数値、シーケンス、マッピング、クラス、インスタンス、および例外です。」などとあるように、Pythonにおける「組み込み型」というのは「ユーザ定義クラスではない」程度の意味が強いです。本家SOでは [このように](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391694/check-if-a-variables-type-is-primitive) JavaユーザがJavaの観点から質問していますが、Pythonにはそのような概念はないと回答されています。これは妥当です。回答には（Pythonにおいては）属性の辞書を持たないオブジェクトならプリミティブだ、とするものもあり+17を得ています。つまり、似たような位置づけにあるとか、そういう次元にはないです。『ビルトインタイプ、ビルトイン型とか、組み込み型と言われます。「ビルトイン」の訳語が「組み込み」だそうです。』の部分はその文脈だと誤った蛇足のように思います。その部分が除去されるとプラス投票入れられる感じです。

Comment: そうですか。私は少し軽く考えすぎていました。ある言語（ここではPythonの）の基本的な型をプリミティブ型と呼ぶことがあるのか？と質問されたいのかな？じゃあ、Pythonだと組み込み型だ。＝似たような位置づけということです。少なくともこのような曖昧なコメントをするべきではありませんでした。意見をいただいたおかげでより解答が充実したものになりました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: dokubeko様、上のように書き換えましたがいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 一度めの書き換えは余計わかりにくくなったのでもう-1したんですが、今のはどういう意味でこう回答したかが簡潔に書かれてわかりやすいと思います！

Answer (score 2):

Q3への回答について補足します。

#### Q3.Pythonでプリミティブデータ型という言い方をしますか？

しないです。[公式ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/3/index.html) で「primitive data type」を検索してみてください。

ただし、非公式な個人ドキュメント（[Learn Python Visually](http://pythonvisually.com/ebook/primitive-data-types.html), [ZetCodeのPython Tutorial](http://zetcode.com/lang/python/datatypes/)）ではそのような表現もみられました。

プリミティブデータ型については、オブジェクトと非オブジェクトで区別する人もいれば、複合型でなければプリミティブと捉える人もいます。Pythonにプリミティブデータ型はあるか？　と質問したら不毛な論争になるかもしません。定義が共有されてない場合があるので、どういう意味で聞いているかによります。

ただ、[他の方の回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/40721/26045) でプリミティブデータ型について、

> ビルトインタイプ、ビルトイン型とか、組み込み型と言われます。

と書かれているのは、指しているものが全く違うので適切ではないと思います（ので、補足として回答させてもらいました）。組み込み型はプリミティブデータ型の言い換えではありません。

Comment: 同意です。Pythonでは全てオブジェクトですから、プリミティブは無いと考えるのが正しいですね。組み込み型の誤用の指摘も正しいです。例えば組み込み型のintだってPythonではオブジェクトですしね。

Comment: Pythonのデータ型が分からず調べた際、(検索結果上位ページで)プリミティブ型との記述があったため(、にも関わらず公式サイトではその記述が見つからなかったため)、疑問に思い質問しました。「プリミティブデータ型については、オブジェクトと非オブジェクトで区別する人もいれば、複合型でなければプリミティブと捉える人もいます」この説明が分かりやすかったです。公式なデータ型ではないけれどもそういう風に解釈している人もいる、と理解しました

Answer (score 1):

> Q2.下記コードで結果に何も表示されないのは何故ですか？
>   ・type()はオブジェクト型のみが対象?

printしないと表示されません。

```
from fractions import Fraction
f = Fraction(5, 7)
print(type(f))
```